# How can i allow having dual/cloning my app in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, clone

The way Facebook, Whatsapp, Skype have an option to have a dual app or a cloned app(another instance of the same app in the same device), how can i achieve this in flutter/dart?

Comment: I think it's platform dependent? You don't "allow" dual app, but the system does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual app feature does not come from the app itself, it's a feature from the system. For example, Samsung has [Dual Messenger](https://www.samsung.com/nz/support/mobile-devices/dual-messenger/) feature on specific models of their phones to allow two seperate accounts on certain apps. MIUI has its own [Dual apps](https://xiaomiui.net/enable-dual-apps-on-budget-xiaomi-phones-8158/) feature. The list of apps available to be cloned might vary between platforms.

Comment: Oh, I never knew this, Thank you.